# Identify the source of log message

Tags: python, logging

Using python logging library, I start getting debug messages of libraries I use. Is there a way to identify the source of those messages in order to suppress them?

For example: When `Trying CDLL(libc.so.6)` appears in my log, 
is there a way to connect it to `shapely` library so I can suppress it by adding:

```
shapely_logger = logging.getLogger('shapely')
shapely_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```